# We have $100$ cards numbered from $1$ to $100$. We pick $6$ cards. What is the probability the smallest card we got will be $20$?

Tags: probability

We have $100$ cards numbered from $1$ to $100$. We pick $6$ cards.  What is the probability the smallest card we got will be $20$?

My attempt:

I can choose $6$ from $100$ cards in $$\frac{100!}{6!94!}$$ ways. There are $$\frac{80!}{5!75!}$$ ways to choose $5$ cards from the $21-100$ cards.

So the probability is $$\frac{\dfrac{80!}{5!75!}}{\dfrac{100!}{6!94!}}$$ correct?

Comment: Why down voted? Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  So you are aware, this isn't a homework site.  Can you show your efforts so far and indicate where you are getting stuck?  (Note :  I did not downvote this question, but I expect the person who did was reacting to the lack of displayed effort).

Comment: @lulu Sure, I am actually confused regarding the part where we draw 6 out of 100 cards. Maybe the probability is 1/100? But I am not sure about that...

Comment: Not all cards are equally likely to be the minimum.   Card $\#100$ can't be the minimum, for example.  Card $\#80$ could be, but it seems very unlikely.  How many ways can you choose $6$ cards?  How many ways can you choose them so that $20$ is the least of them?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the help. I can chose 6 from 100 cards with 100!/(6!*94!) ways. There are 80!/(5!*75!) ways to chose 5 cards from the 21-100 cards.

Comment: Perfect.  Do you see how that solves your problem?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the help! So the probability is (80!/(5!*75!)) / (100!/(6!*94!)), correct?

Comment: Once again, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

As lulu stated in the comments, your answer is correct.

Comment: If I wanted the probability the smallest to be 20 and the biggest to be 50, then is binomial[29, 4]/binomial[100,6] the correct answer?

Comment: That is correct.  Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.